# How to pass parent reference if the consuming field is a custom object lookup (creating parent and child in 1 statement)

Tags: apex

I'm following [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) in the documentation for creating parent and child records in a single statement using foreign keys. It works for the Account and Opportunity scenario. But in the scenario wherein the child is not a standard object, it doesn't work.

For example, what I did is:

```
// The parent
Case parentCase = new Case();
parentCase.ExternalId__c = 'external_id_123abc';

// The case that will act as the foreign key that will connect the parent and the child
Case caseReference = new Case(ExternalId__c = 'external_id_123abc');

// The child
My_Custom_Object__c co = new My_Custom_Object__c();
cs.Name = 'test';
cs.Case__c = caseReference;
```

This code won't compile because `cs.Case__c = caseReference` would throw an error of `Illegal assignment from Case to Id`. Not sure how to go around this error.

The main objective here is to lessen the the soql statements that I need to fire. With this approach, I can create a parent and all of the dynamically created children at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turns out to be rather simple, if non-obvious: change `cs.Case__c` to `cs.Case__r`.

When you're dealing with relationship fields in Apex, the `__c` version of the lookup field is typed as an `Id` value. The `__r` variant of a lookup field to `Some_Object__c` is typed as a `Some_Object__c`, and can be assigned (or extracted as) an sObject class instance in Apex. The `__r` name of a child relationship is typed as a `List<Child_Object__c>` and can be interacted with as you'd expect.

These latter two are actually parallel to how standard fields work. Look at the difference in type between `Contact.Account` and `Contact.AccountId`, for example, and the type of `Account.Contacts`. You can safely do `someContact.Account.Name` (in both SOQL and Apex), and you can do `Account a = someContact.Account`, but you can't do either of those things with `AccountId`. It's just that the syntax doesn't make this distinction quite as clear when dealing with custom fields.